# PyV8 Issue Sublime Text3

Tags: python, ubuntu, sublimetext, pyv8

im having some problems and my new Ubuntu 12.04 64 installation.

I have installed sublime text, i got both, 2/3 and both are giving this error when i try to install EMMET i have research a lot of info, also trying to install PYV8 Manually, but its not working.

```
PyV8: Creating new thread
Emmet: Creating thread

Emmet: Loading https://api.github.com/repos/emmetio/pyv8-binaries/contents
Emmet: Loading PyV8 binary from https://raw.github.com/emmetio/pyv8-binaries/master/pyv8-linux64-p3.zip
Exception in thread Thread-30:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X/threading.py", line 639, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "X/threading.py", line 825, in run
  File "/home/zilashak/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Emmet.sublime-package/emmet/pyv8loader.py", line 271, in run
    return self.trigger('error', exit_code=self.thread.exit_code, progress=self)
  File "/home/zilashak/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Emmet.sublime-package/emmet/pyv8loader.py", line 290, in trigger
    c(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_error() got an unexpected keyword argument 'progress'
```

So if anyone knows how to solve it, ill thanks you a lot.

-----------------------------------------------------SOLUTION ----------------------------------
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!SOLVED!!!!!!!!!!

Solution here for everyone!!

Ok for everyone out there that is having this problem, after lot of research i have found the solution (FINALLY!)
First of, install python3.3

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.3
```

Then you have to download manually the package of PyV8 from
https://raw.github.com/emmetio/pyv8-binaries/master/pyv8-linux64-p3.zip
After you download you have to unzip the file, and you wil have to copy the 2 files inside the new folder into your
.config/sublime-text3/Installed Packages/PyV8/

You have to create the folder PyV8 previously.
At the end its should look, like this!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuozE.jpg

Comment: Thank you very much. I had been stuck for days and couldn't find any solution, thanks to you i have emmet installed :D

Comment: @Zilashak: on StackOverflow when you solve your own problem you should post it as a regular answer and mark it as accepted, without changing the original question body and title.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and also other solutions found on github and... nothing worked. But having a lucky day i stumbled upon this answer: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues/476

**To all the guys who couldn't resolve it till now:** If all the other solutions didn't work for you, try that! It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the same issue here [here](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues/417), using "disable_pyv8_update": true is  the suggested fix.

Comment: I have already check out all those post, and search, and nothing at the moment is fixing my issue. At this moment i have got it working on sublime text 2, but no way its work on sublime text 3